# Troubleshooting my code - Key Error results when referencing by key name taken from raw_input()

Tags: python, dictionary, raw-input

This part of the equation is the part I don't need help on. This basically asks the user to input the amount of player in the game, and creates a sub-dictionary for every player within one main dictionary:

```
ans = raw_input('Enter Amount of Players: ').lower()
if ans == '2':
    a = raw_input('What is Player 1 named: ')
    b = raw_input('What is Player 2 named: ')
    cf={a:{}, b:{}}
    p1 = raw_input(a + ", what is your city named: ")  
    p2 = raw_input(b + ", what is your city named: ") 
    cf[a][p1] = '50'
    cf[b][p2] = '50'
    for key, cf in cf.items():
        print(key)
        for attribute, value in cf.items():
            print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value))
```

Here is the part I need help on:

```
##This function may be screwing it up
def cva(x):
    y = cf[ques][city]
    y = float(y)
    return x + y

while True:
    one = raw_input("Type 'view' to view civil form, type 'change' to change civil order,   or 'add' to add a city: ")
 if one == 'change':
        ques = raw_input('Enter Name of Player That Will Change His/Her Civil Form: ').lower()
        city = raw_input(ques + 'Enter Name Of City That Will Change Civil Form: ').lower()
        inc = raw_input(ques + ' Enter Amount of change for ' + city + ": ").lower()
        cf[ques][city]=cva(float(inc))
        for key, cf in cf.items():
            print(key)
            for attribute, value in cf.items():
                print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value))
```

Lets say I inputted the name 'evan' and his city 'LA', an error would come up saying 'KeyError: 'evan'. How do I get this to work?

Comment: They `KeyError` will only happen if there is no key already for `evan` you can either pre-populate the dictionary, or use a defaultdict, or check the dictionary each layer at a time for each key, and add it if it does not exist already.

Comment: As a side note: try to use clear variable names. For a code review, reading variable namens like `a`, `b`, `cf`, etc. can become quite hard.

Comment: @inbar rose - I think if you have a 'create' method and an 'update' method, the 'update' should not create new records, it should drive the action back to 'create' to make the new record, then return to 'update' for updates. Automatically added records without some sort of prompting / user interaction seems like a recipe for later disaster.

Comment: @selllikesybok Why did you tag me?

Comment: @Inbar Rose - My comment was a reply to my understanding of yours, which appeared to suggest that the misbehaving code segment should check if the key exists (I agree) and add the key if it does not (I disagree - at least in the context of doing so within the specific context of the example misbehaving code).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the Player has been previously added to the dictionary. You should also normalize the inputs and dictionary keys.

Assuming you do not need to support case sensitive unique names for people, then adding:

```
if ques.lower() not in [key.lower() for key in cf.keys()]:
    print "Player record does not exist - please create player before updating."
    continue
```

after the player name input would be one way to handle this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to update your `dic` before you call the `cva` function. Otherwise,  the `y = cf[ques][city]` in the `cva` function won't have the updated city value.

ex :

```
while True:
    one = raw_input("Type 'view' to view civil form, type 'change' to change civil order,   or 'add' to add a city: ")
    if one == 'change':
        ques = raw_input('Enter Name of Player That Will Change His/Her Civil Form: ').lower()
        city = raw_input(ques + 'Enter Name Of City That Will Change Civil Form: ').lower()
        inc = raw_input(ques + ' Enter Amount of change for ' + city + ": ").lower()
        cf[ques].update({city:0}) # create the entry in the dic
        cf[ques][city] = cva(float(inc))
        # ...
```

And as @selllikesybok said, add some code that verify the dic before iterate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is due to a bug in the first snippet of code which you think is OK.
Note that in the`for`loop at the end where you have:

```
    for key, cf in cf.items():
        print(key)
        for attribute, value in cf.items():
            print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value))
```

However the issue is with the`for key, cf in cf.items():`which changes the value of`cf`when it executes.

If you change the name of the second target variable from`cf`to something else which does not conflict with any existing variable, your second part won't get the`KeyError`on`'evan'`any longer.
For example:

```
    for key, info in cf.items():
        print(key)
        for attribute, value in info.items():
            print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value))
```